# Android CTS - No available device matching the config's requirements

Tags: android-source, cts, bsp

I am trying to do android compatibility test on **SC20  EVb** by using `cts-tradefed` and while trying run cts test by using `cts run --plan CTS`, it shows this log:

> No available device matching the config's requirements for cmd id 1.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

while in tardefed check whether connected device is detected or not with below command:

cts-tf > list devices
Serial    State   Allocation  Product             Variant       Build            Battery

1770c061  ONLINE  Available   msm8998             msm8998       QKQ1.191014.001  67

1d9d493d  ONLINE  Available   msm8998             msm8998       QKQ1.191014.001  67

Above command should display all connected android devices and allocation status.
If your device is not listed within the output check with the adb installation within the host.
If CTS is triggered on the device Allocation status will be changed from Available to Allocated.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure first that you have an adb connection with the device. It the device is connected over adb and you are still facing this issue, please wait for a while, sometimes it might take 5-10 mins to start.Hope its helpful.